# Adding two "Bigint" byte arrays together

Tags: java

I'm having trouble trying to add two "big integer" byte arrays together which are stored in reverse order to help with math. Here is my constructor.

```
public class Intzilla {
public byte[] digits;
//private byte negative = -1;
private byte zero = 0;
private byte positive = 1;
private byte posNegZero = 0;
private boolean negative;
private String inputString;

public Intzilla() {
    this("0");
}

public Intzilla(String s) {
    String tempString = s;
    inputString = s;
    tempString = tempString.trim();
    if(tempString.substring(0,1).equals("-")){
        negative = true;
        tempString = tempString.substring(1);
    } else if(tempString.substring(0,1).equals("+")){
        negative = false;
        tempString = tempString.substring(1);
    }else {
        negative = false;
    }

    while((tempString.substring(0,1).equals("0")) && (tempString.length() > 1)){
        tempString = tempString.substring(1);
    }

    digits = new byte[tempString.length()];

    for(int i = 0; i < tempString.length(); i++){
        String currentChar = tempString.substring(i, i+1);
        byte tempDigits = Byte.parseByte(currentChar);
        digits[(digits.length - 1) -i] = tempDigits;
    }
}
```

And here is my attempted plus method so far. Getting a "possible lossy conversion from into to byte".

```
 public Intzilla plus(Intzilla addend) {
    byte carry = 0;
    byte mod = 10;
    Intzilla result = new Intzilla();

    for(int i = 0; i <= addend.digits.length-1; i++) {
        result.digits[i] = (byte)(this.digits[i] + addend.digits[i] + carry)% mod;
        carry = (byte)(this.digits[i] + addend.digits[i] + carry) / 10;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Hi David, do you haev any questions today?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm confused why I'm getting a "possible lossy conversion form int to byte" when it should be taking the stored byte in this.digits[i] and addend.digits[i].

Comment: try `carry = (this.digits[i] + addend.digits[i] + carry) / (byte) 10;`

Comment: If you are adding one byte with another byte then it may exceed the max byte value

Comment: I can see why that would work! But, unfortunately I'm still getting a lossy error. Attached is an imgur link to my console and the exact errors I'm getting and where. [Console Screencap](http://i.imgur.com/dWj0za8.png)

Comment: As well, isn't the max byte value 127? That would be impossible from adding two single digit bytes together.

Comment: how about just forcing the cast then `carry = (byte)(this.digits[i] + addend.digits[i] + carry) / 10;`

Comment: The compiler doesn't know that you are limiting the data to single digit bytes, only what is potentially possible.

Comment: I appreciate this help. Even forcing the cast it still gives me a lossy error. I have no idea where this supposed int is coming from.

Comment: This is my current method, I changed the carry and mod to bytes as well as the forced cast.

Comment: `carry = (byte)(this.digits[i] + addend.digits[i] + carry) / 10;` (new to SO and having trouble copying multiple lines)

Comment: please edit your question to show the definition and instantiation of `digits` and well as your default constrcutor

Answer (score 0):

This format works

```
    byte [] newbytes = new byte [20];
    byte [] oldbytes = new byte [20];

    for (int x = 0; x < oldbytes.length; x++) {
        newbytes [x] = (byte) ((newbytes[x] + oldbytes [x]) / 100);
    }
```